# Python Attack Implementation on RC4 Cipher

Tags: python, rc4-cipher

I have a assignment to implement a RC4 attacks and I am stuck.

This is the link to the simulation, the simulator will take the message and encrypt and decrypt in size 128 bytes.

Click on the `simulation.jar` to generate the message between the server and client. I need to find the shared secret key.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mn19bknhjsn9rwz/Simulation.zip?dl=0

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: stuck on how to find the shared secret key

Comment: Sounds like that's not a programming issue, it's a learning cryptography issue. StackOverflow can't really help with that.